# ReactCSSTransitionGroup is not adding any classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to integrate ReactCSSTransitionGroup in order to have some very basic fade in/out animations but no classes are added to the children. Nothing helpful in the console. Am I making some obvious misstake?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import history from '../history'
import { Map } from 'immutable'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react/lib/ReactTransitionGroup'

import TwitchChannel from './twitchChannel'
import TwitchChannelAddForm from './twitchChannelAddForm'

const component = React.createClass({

 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>
    <TwitchChannelAddForm />
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="animation" transitionAppear={true}>
     {this.props.channels.map(ch => 
      <TwitchChannel channel_id={ch.get('id')} key={ch.get('id')} />
     )}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
   </div>
  )
 }
})

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
    channels: state.getIn(['twitch', 'channels'], Map({})).toArray()
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(component)
```

Css

```css
animation-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.animation-enter.animation-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the css for your animations ?

Comment: Yes, edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the issue.

I was getting an error when i tried to import the 'react-addons-transition-group' package with npm so i referenced the package directly ('react/lib/ReactTransitionGroup'). This fixed all errors but the code itself was not working either.

After searching through the npm i found the package 'react-addons-css-transition-group' and after installing and importing that I got it to work.